# Unable to use the methods of GraphicsDevice

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I've been trying to learn MonoGame from their official documentation.

However, I've hit a snag.

In their code, they've done the following...

```
Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X,
GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);
```

Now, the problem I'm getting is this. Whenever I use the bit of code `GraphicsDevice.Viewport`, MonoGame does not allow it and gives the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'GraphicsDevice.Viewport'

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a MonoGame problem. It's got to do with the way C# resolves properties and types.

If we take a look at the [`Viewport` property of `GraphicsDevice`](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/GraphicsDevice.cs#L636) we can see that it's a *non-static property* of the `GraphicsDevice` class.

```
public class GraphicsDevice
{
    public Viewport Viewport { get; set; }
}
```

The other piece to this puzzle is that there's also a [`GraphicsDevice` property on the `Game` class](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Game.cs#L263).

```
public class Game
{
    public GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice { get; }
}
```

What this means is that when you use the line `GraphicsDevice.Viewport` within the context of the `Game` class, it has a different meaning to when you use it outside the context of the `Game` class.

For example, if you put your code inside the `Update` method of a class that derives from `Game` it will work.

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);
    }
}
```

The reason this works, is because it's using the `GraphicsDevice` property from the base `Game` class in this context.

On the other hand, if you put the same code inside a class that doesn't have a `GraphicsDevice` property you'll get the error in your question.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y + GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);
    }
}
```

I suspect the cause is something like that, although, it's difficult to tell with the limited information in your question.

There's multiple ways to solve this problem. One way is to inject the `GraphicsDevice` into the constructor of your custom class and use that instead.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private GraphicsDevice _graphicsDevice;

    public MyClass(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        _graphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(_graphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.X, _graphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Y + _graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.